# How to SUM values in cell with Text Prefix

Tags: excel-formula

I have a column in excel with the values with currency prefix like: Rs. 100, rs. 200, rs 125 etc., I want to sum the digits and discard the ("Rs. , rs., rs") text; also how to add "Rs." in resultant SUM automatically?

Comment: Is there always a space between the values and the text and is it the only spacein the cell?

Comment: yes, it is almost the case

Comment: There may be a valid reason not to do this (e.g. importing preformatted data from plain-text), but would it be easier to remove the "RS" entirely (leaving just the numbers), and then Format the columns as Currency (Ctrl+1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out..

```
=SUMPRODUCT(MID(0&A1, LARGE(INDEX(ISNUMBER(--MID(A1, ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))), 1)) * ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))), 0), ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))))+1, 1) * 10^ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1)))/10)
```

this formula will pick all the number from cell

Drag the formula in Column B (in my case) and have `=sum(B:B)` formula at the end

[image]

Comment: Its giving value of 1st cell only

Comment: yup, you have repeat the formula for all the cells

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Is there any way to get the sum in single cell without EXTRACTING values in another column and THEN do the SUM?

Comment: I don't think so,, but you can have the formula in column `zz` and hide it and have `=sum(zz:zz)` in column `B1`. This just an work around.. if this fix's the issue mark this answer as correct..

Comment: Caution: this formula messes up if fractions are used.  E.g., `Rs. 100.50` yields `10050`.  Users should be warned of this or perhaps modify to accommodate that situation.

Answer (score 2):

The formula to extract numbers in your scenario is:
`=--RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH(" ", A1))`
Once extracted, you should be able to add them up.
Credit to @PraveenDA for pointing out `--` prefix tip to convert text to number.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it does extract the values but I am unable to do the SUM on the values which is not the case with Praveen DA's solution.

Comment: prefix the formula with `--` will convert the text output to value `=--RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH(" ", A1))`

Comment: Great... Solved